# Proving identity $\sum_{j\geq 1}[(j+t)^{-1}-j^{-1}]=\sum_{k\geq 1}\zeta (k+1)(-t)^{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, zeta-functions

Motivation: In S.J. Patterson's *An introduction to the theory of the Riemann
Zeta-Function* it is proved (p.132) that

$\displaystyle -\Gamma ^{\prime }(t)/\Gamma (t)=\gamma +t^{-1}+\underset{j\geq 1}{\sum }[(j+t)^{-1}-j^{-1}]$.

In Exercise A4.1 (p.135) one is asked to show that if $|t|<1$

$\displaystyle -\Gamma ^{\prime }(t)/\Gamma (t)=\gamma +t^{-1}+\underset{k\geq 1}{\sum }\zeta (k+1)(-t)^{k}$.

**Question:** How does one prove that

$\displaystyle\underset{j\geq 1}{\sum }[(j+t)^{-1}-j^{-1}]=\underset{k\geq 1}{\sum }\zeta (k+1)(-t)^{k}\qquad $for $|t|<1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac1{1-x}$. For $|t| < \min j = 1$, we have

$$ (j + t)^{-1} = j^{-1} \left( 1 + \frac tj \right)^{-1} = j^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( -\frac tj\right)^k, $$

thus the LHS is

$$ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-t)^k}{j^{k+1}}
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-t)^k}{j^{k+1}}
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-t)^k \left( \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{j^{k+1}} \right) 
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-t)^k \zeta(k+1) $$

Answer (score 4):

Use
$$
\frac{1}{j + t} = \frac{1}{j} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{t}{j}} = \frac{1}{j} \sum_{k \geq 0} (-t)^k j^{- k}
$$
to obtain
$$
\sum_{j \geq 1} [ (j + t)^{-1} - j^{-1} ] =
\sum_{j \geq 1} \sum_{k \geq 1} (-t)^k j^{-k-1} = \sum_{k \geq 1} \zeta (k + 1) (-t)^k .
$$